# How to factorize $49403$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want a way without calculator that factorizes $49403$.I mean a way like that we factorize $391$.

$391=20^2-3^2=(20-3)(20+3)=17*23$

For $49403$ we can do this:

$49403=258^2-131^2=(258-131)(258+131)=127*389$

But we cannot guess that without calculator.Any hints?

Comment: We can calculate differences of square numbers with three digits by hand. Of course, it is not very elegant. We can also perform some factorization algorithms by hand here, e.g., Pollard-rho. In general, perhaps, one should use factorization algorithms.

Comment: I cheated by looking at your calculation: $$3\cdot49403=148209=148225-16=385^2-4^2.$$
Small multiples can be checked similarly relatively quickly, but this is not a very good method. The earlier tools did look for such presentation based on the theory of quadratic residues. Dickson and his students had machines using bicycle chain and several gears of different sizes, each with a prime number of teeth, together with a mechanism that halted the turning of the crank when the position indicated a difference that was, if not a square, at least quadratic residue modulo all those primes.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen.Yes but it isn't easy to guess it can be solved if  we multiply by 3.

Comment: No, it isn't easy to guess. But there are other ways squares and quadratic residues can be used to reduce the number of prime factor candidates to be tested. See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/774312/11619) for some elementary observations.

Comment: Just a side-comment: factorization is known to be a very hard problem without any obvious systematic approaches. That's precisely why it's used for encryption: not even a computer can do it very efficiently. The answer is thus: unless the difference of squares decomposition is painfully obvious, you're pretty much stuck with trial&error (or one of the fancy optimized algorithms which do trial and error in a more ofuscated way).

Comment: This is not a good method. Almost all numbers can be expressed as the difference of 2 squares